# Spring Integration | jdbc outbound gateway/adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am working on a Spring integration application, I have a List of Maps which I need to insert into a table.

I have used jdbc:outbound-gateway or adapter to insert a record to the table.

But how to insert all records from my list of map using jdbc:outbound-gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<splitter>` upstream to your `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>`.

We have an [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3530) on the matter, but before that fix we should split our collections before insert.